# Receiving parameter in page navigation in modern ui

Tags: c#, wpf, modern-ui

I use Modern UI framework, and I use page navigation feature

```
    var bs = new BBCodeBlock();
    try
    {
        bs.LinkNavigator.Navigate(new Uri("../SomePage.xaml", UriKind.Relative), this);
    }
    catch (Exception error)
    {
        ModernDialog.ShowMessage(error.Message, FirstFloor.ModernUI.Resources.NavigationFailed, MessageBoxButton.OK);
    }
```

I would like to pass a certain parameter, say "A" to the navigated page and receive it over there.

Comment: See my answer to similar question
http://stackoverflow.com/a/27621374/2601824

Answer (score 1):

If you use an IoC container, you can get a reference to the ViewModel for `SomePage.xaml`, and set the parameter there before navigating.